# alt-tab hides apps on other monitor

Tags: window-management, display, window-manager

I'm trying to use elementary on my multi-monitor setup and I have this annoying issue with switching apps

Is there any way to keep apps visible on the other monitor and switch apps only on the active monitor

Comment: The answer is no, there is no way, which makes this a feature request according to the community.